# Unable to GET Data from mysql with AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm having trouble trying to get data from a database. The code will only retrieve the first row of data from the Database. The data is correct but it does not matter what information I put into my html input field the data is the same in the new row that is added. Any help resolving this would be fantastic.

If someone was going to point out that I have both "POST" and "GET" mixed in my code, I could understand as that being a possible problem, but neither when matching would retrieve data from the DB, other than the first row of data in the table.

Any help with this would be great!!! Thanks to all who provide an answer in advance.

My HTML code:

index.php

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h3 class="h4 text-center"><input type="text" name="barcode" id="barcode" size="90" class="col-md-9" value="" method="GET" placeholder="Barcode / Product Name"></h3>

             </div>
        </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"><p class=""></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table id="report" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>SKU</td>
                        <td>Model</td>
                        <td>Item Description</td>
                        <td>Qty</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 <?php get_item(); ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
       </div>
    </div>
```

This is my AJAX script

```
<script>
var inp = $("#barcode");
// where #txt is the id of the textbox

$("#barcode").keyup(function (event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13)
{
    if (inp.val().length > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "GET", //Also tried POST method. Didn't work either
            data: {id: inp.val()},
            success: function(response)
            {
                values = response.split(' - ');
                $('#report tr:last').after(
                    "<tr class='table-row'>" +
                    "<td class=''>" + values[1] + "</td>" +
                    "<td class=''>" + values[2] + "</td>" +
                    "<td class=''>" + values[3] + "</td>" +
                    "<td class=''>" + values[4] + "</td></tr>");
            }});
    }
    $('input[name=barcode]').val('');
    }

 });
</script>
```

Here is my php code

```
function get_item(){
global $con;    
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $query = query("SELECT * FROM items");
        confirm($query);
    while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
        $sku = $row['sku'];
        $model = $row['category'];
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $qty = $row['qty'];

    echo($id.' - '.$sku.' - '.$model.' - '.$desc.' - '.$qty);
    die();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why u use method in input type ?

Comment: You just created the function try to call it on index.php like get_item(). then it will run on the page otherwise its just a function.

Comment: what you geting in responce :   success: function(response)
            { conslole.log(response); }

Comment: Where you use `$_POST['id']` in your code?

Comment: @Vicky. I was trying a bunch of different things to see if I could get a different result. I was thinking maybe the method was missing in the input field.

Comment: @Ali . Sorry I was calling the function in my index file but it was in my header section.

Comment: @ShaluSinghal. I didn't think about adding the 'id" in the POST. I did this after reading your comment, but the result is the same. I only get the first row of data from the Table in the DB.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php check this link and try to direct hit you page and var_dump($query);

Comment: @cpt-crunchy you want all the records or just one row?

Comment: @ShaluSinghal One item for each row.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `die();` function call out of your while loop. It gets called rigth at the end of the first loop terminating your php script.

Comment: I moved the die(); function out of the while loop. But still the same results.